# How to access elements from UI in Qt indirectly?

Tags: c++, qt

I have created 3 classes in Qt: `MainController`, `ViewController` and `MainWindow`.

`MainWindow` contains getters to allow `ViewController` to update the UI. The `MainController` can only access the UI elements with help of `ViewController`. In order to connect the signals in the `ViewController` to the slots in `MainController`, I need to access the UI elements in `MainWindow` from `MainController`. How can I do this?

`MainController`:

```
connect(m_viewController->mainWindow_getStartListeningPushButton(), &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainController::startOnlineMode);
```

`ViewController`:

```
QPushButton* ViewController::startDialog_getStartListeningPushButton()
{
    return m_mainWindow->getStartListeningPushButton();
}
```

`MainWindow`:

```
QPushButton* MainWindow::getStartListeningPushButton()
{
    return ui.startListeningPushButton;
}
```

When I try to build this I get errors. I think it has to do with the pointers, but I don't know how to solve this...

[image]

Comment: "When I try to build this I get errors.", please always include the errors in the question, and indicate which lines they happen at (because editor line numbers don't mean anything in the question).

Comment: @hyde You had to wait 2 more seconds :)

Comment: Please copy and paste the *error text*, not a *screenshot*.

Comment: I think the error meant that you are missing an include. Although I only had 2 seconds to look..

Comment: Well, the error pretty clearly indicates that the problem is in `&MainController::startOnlineMode`, doesn't it?

Comment: This method is empty, so I don't understand how it would be possible...

Comment: Is the code that I shared with you correct?

Comment: Your problem is in the code you are not showing us.

Comment: Ok, so I can assume that the included  code in my question is correct? That is basically my question...

Comment: The code you posted looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no problems in the code I posted.